# OverFeat paper questions

Tags: machine-learning, conv-neural-network, object-detection

Can anybody please explain some details of "Overfeat multi-scale classification"?

I was reading the overfeat paper<sup>1</sup> and came through its section "3.3 Multi-Scale classification". I am unable to understand how max pooling operation is applied, what are pixel offsets and how it repeated 3x3 times.

Basically, I am unable to understand these two points in the paper into section 3.3 Multi-Scale Classification:

> - (b) Each of unpooled maps undergoes a 3x3 max pooling operation (non-overlapping regions), repeated 3x3 times for (∆x, ∆y) pixel offsets of {0, 1, 2}.
> - (c) This produces a set of pooled feature maps, replicated (3x3) times for different (∆x, ∆y) combinations.

<sub>1. Sermanet, P, et al. (2014). OverFeat: Integrated Recognition, Localization and Detection using Convolutional Networks. arxiv.org/pdf/1312.6229 ([pdf](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1312.6229.pdf)).</sub>